# Android - Count the number of tap on the screen in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

A pretty straightforward question: I have a fragment, and if a certain condition is met, I want it to count the number of tap on the screen.

So I did a

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           count_tap++;
       }
   });
```

That seems to almost work, but on certain items of my view, the components are not observed. Do I have to give and id to all my components (even those who are normally static xml) and the set them with the same `setOnClickListener` ?

Or is it the wrong way to do that at all ?

Comment: Post your complete fragment.

Answer (score 2):

If you need root view of your activity or fragment, use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.

Like:

```
View rootView= getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

Set `View.OnClickListener` to this view:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           count_tap++;
       }
   });
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't do the trick at all... Tapping on some elements like a text view are not counted.. I ould contourn the problem by making the user tap on a button but I'd rather not if possible

Comment: This is happening because you have set `View.setOnClickListener` on `TextView` which is called on tapping `TextView` instead of root view listener.

Comment: No I've set it on the new rootview i created like you suggested. Like I said, when tapping on element like a textview, the tap is not counted at all. I'd like it to work on all my screen

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your fragment's root view and count touch UPs.

```
public class TouchCounter extends FrameLayout {
    private int touchCount;


    public TouchableOverlay(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                touchCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public int getTouchCount() {
        return touchCount;
    }
}
```

In your fragment:

```
.....

private TouchCounter touchCounter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        return addTouchCounter(view);
}
.....

private void addTouchCounter(View view) {
     touchCounter = new TouchCounter(getContext());
     touchCounter.addView(view);
     return touchCounter;
}
```

You can also add a case for ACTION_DOWN and calculate time difference between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP/CANCEL if you want to count only clicks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any buttons or other touch gestures in your layout, Here's another idea that might work, but i guess there are more elegant ways to do this.
You can cover your layout with another transparent `View`, and use this transparent `View` to count the clicks.

Something like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                /// instead of this LinearLayout you can put your layout
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/click_counter_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Instead of your layout you should inflate `view_frame`, and set a click listener on the `click_counter_layout`. hope it will work...